# Site links in page rendered in default language, despite language 'L' flag, when requesting page with external call using wget or curl

Tags: curl, typo3, multilingual, typo3-7.6.x, multisite

I am creating a simple `404 page not found` handler for a T3 multi-site site with 2 languages using the `T3 userfunc`.

Within this handler, I fetch the 404 regular T3 content pages with the language parameter the user used while browsing the site, something like `https://www.xyz.de/404-seite-nicht-gefunden/?L=0` or `https://www.xyz.de/404-page-not-found/?L=1`.

When I call these 404 pages using any browser, I get all contents and Links within the content and navigation with their correct link text, language-specific slugs and L-parameter all correctly rendered. Just as I expected it.

However, when using `curl` or `wget` ( or within my 404 page handler the method `GeneralUtility:getUrl` ), I get correct contents, **BUT** when using the English language Flag `L=1` to fetch the English 404 page, all navigation slugs are rendered in default site Language ( German in this case ) containing the English language flag `L=1` appended.
For instance, I get `https://www.xyz.de/ueber-uns/?L=1`, whereas it should be `https://www.xyz.de/about-us/L=1`. As said, the link texts appear in correct language though.

This problem I can reproduce by simply using `wget` or `curl` on the command line. It gives me the same results.

What could be the issue here? I don't think cookies play any role in this case.

Other than that there are - afaik - no problems with the language configuration in T3, all works perfectly fine. The site is not fully translated and not 1:1, English is only a little, selected subset of some German site. So I am pretty much out of ideas.

I could resolve that issue using static 404 pages with the same site layout, but then I loose the dynamic flavor and I would have to create 6 distinct static 404 HTML pages ( 3 T3 sites x 2 languages ). I think this is odd ...

If I need to paste some configuration, code or give addt. info, please let me know.

Any hint or help is greatly appreciated.

**edit**

I believe, a possible cause of my problem was the `realurl` cache (Thanks to @Krystian and his post bringing me on this lane).

Once I truncated all `realurl` cache DB tables and its entries, the problem disappeared. Perhaps I had - due to all my testing and adjusting the `realurl` configuration - cache entries that were recurring, whatsoever. 
The cleanup did it for now and I will see within the next 2 days, when finalizing this task, if this issue was completely resolved.

**Moral of this story may be:** Always clean caches when you work on issues that rely on such data. Or switch to debug mode, no-caching, etc ...

Answer (score 2):

When you are logged to TYPO3 backend the caching is partially disabled and if you are getting url from curl level then you are not logged to BE.
So plz log out from TYPO3 backend and check if you have the same behaviour in browser level.

Comment: Yes, there was indeed a different behavior. I did the test on on of my machines I have not used for this T3 project. However, your answer give me a hint: The actual problem - or one main problems - was the realurl cache tables that needed a purge.